# What is the current vaccination regulation for international students for US universities?

Tags: graduate-admissions, covid-19

Considering the elapsed time of Covid crisis, have any vaccination regulations been put into place for international students waiting to apply for masters programs in US or related research programs in general? If so, are both doses required if already vaccinated by one dose of a two-dose vaccine?

Comment: https://www.chronicle.com/blogs/live-coronavirus-updates/heres-a-list-of-colleges-that-will-require-students-to-be-vaccinated-against-covid-19

Comment: Whatever the regulations, you are much better off if you are fully vaccinated, including the likely two week wait after the second shot. Many places that don't require it base their policy on misinformation and a rejection of science, willing to let people die unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [H]ave any vaccination regulations been put into place for international students waiting to apply for masters programs in US or related research programs in general?

I find it incredibly unlikely there are vaccinations requirements to *apply*, however if accepted, it is extremely likely you will be required to have a COVID vaccine (among others) by the time you start (presumably next fall at this point). If you already have one dose, then I see no reason to continue holding off applying.

Indeed, if you are coming from a country with poor access to vaccines, the university will probably be willing to vaccinate you when you arrive, assuming the US will let you in without a vaccine next year.

Comment: _it is extremely likely you will be required to have a COVID vaccine_ - I'm not sure about that.  In several states now, universities are not even allowed to require COVID vaccines, and I'm not convinced such a requirement will be a universal standard by next year.

Comment: There's a dichotomy: In some states, local laws allow for universities to require vaccination, and then these universities generally do. In other states, law specifically prohibits universities to require vaccination. It is, like everything, largely a question of which party governs a state.

Comment: I'm hoping that by fall of 2022 either those states will come to their sense or the feds will step in. But either way, it's rather moot  to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Vaccination policies differ among US universities; some require it, and some don't. It's possible that some universities which don't now require it will in the future, for example when the FDA gives full approval. Your question can only be answered on a case-by-case basis, by looking at the websites of individual universities.

That said, most places which do require the vaccine are requiring full vaccination (e.g. the second dose).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am about to get my second shot and was worried about applying to schools in middle of my vaccination. I think it wouldn't be an issue while applying but I'll look for the schools I wish to apply just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @K_lash96 Oh, if you're going to get your second shot soon, then I agree with what Azor Ahai -him- said: I'm virtually certain that there's no vaccine requirement to apply, only to be vaccinated before you show up on campus. I suppose you could check to be sure, but it's probably unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will certainly check vaccination requirement for particular school before hand.